# How to change Wii language in certain channels?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, miiverse

So I just got a Wii because I wanted to play some old games, but if I open a channel, let’s say the Mii channel, it’s in Japanese and I am not able to change it, no matter what I do. The system language is set as English and the region is set as US, but if I open the Mii channel everything is in Japanese. How can I change Japanese to English?